# ¿Cómo elegir el lugar específico donde adsense pueda poner su publicación?

Tags: google-adsense

Esta pregunta puede que ya este hecha pero no la encontré, así que gracias por su comprensión.

Ahora bien, ¿Cómo elegir el lugar específico donde adsense pueda poner su publicación?

Tengo una sitio con los anuncios pero me aparecen de forma aleatoria y mueven el diseño de forma no deseada, me gustaría algo que permita indicar donde quiero estos anuncios y que solo aparezcan ahí.

Por su atención y comprensión, muchas gracias.

por cierto no puedo poner la etiqueta adsense, gracias.

Comment: muy buena pregunta... todavía no llegue a esa parte de mi desarrollo, pero vi que en semantic-ui que es la capa de estilos que uso, creo haber visto un apartado al respecto... pero supongo que se manejará con containers... calculo... por ahi estoy diciendo una pavada... pero bueno...

Comment: Ayuda! tengo la respuesta y me gustaría saber si puedo responder a mi pregunta o solo la comento?

Comment: puedes responder a tu propia pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un bloque de anuncios de AdSense y administrarlo con su cuenta, siga estos pasos:

1.- En el panel de navegación de la izquierda, haga clic en Mis anuncios.
2.- Seleccione su producto. Por ejemplo, si desea mostrar anuncios en su sitio web, seleccione "Contenido".
3.- Haga clic en + Nuevo bloque de anuncios.
4.- Introduzca el nombre del bloque de anuncios. Es una buena idea utilizar un nombre descriptivo único que le ayude a encontrar este bloque de anuncios más tarde.
5.- En la sección "Tamaño del anuncio", elija el tamaño de los anuncios que le gustaría mostrar.
6.-En el menú desplegable Tipo de anuncio, seleccione el tipo de anuncio que desee mostrar en sus páginas.
7.-En el menú desplegable Si no hay anuncios disponibles, elija lo que quiera que mostremos en su bloque de anuncios en caso de que Google no disponga de anuncios segmentados.
8.- Haga clic en Guardar y obtener el código.
9.- En el cuadro "Código del anuncio" que aparece, deje el tipo de código configurado como "Asíncrono" (el valor predeterminado), a menos que desee utilizar el código de anuncio síncrono. Más información sobre el código de anuncio asíncrono.
10.- Copie y pegue el código del anuncio en el código fuente HTML de las páginas en las que le gustaría que se publicaran anuncios. Si no sabe cómo hacerlo, puede consultar la Guía de implementación del código.
Aqui esta la fuenta directa, me ayudo mucho.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6002575